# R: Setting certain column values to a variable

Tags: r

I have an R assignment where it requires me to perform a hypothesis test, but however the data is stored in an excel file.  Within the excel file, I am given 3 columns of data, and I am supposed to test whether the average age of females is less than males, given that the value assigned to females is 1, and the value assigned to males is 0.

I want to extract the data from the column so that I can store all data for females to the variable "females", and all the data for males to the variable "male".  How can I do that?  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] including a sample dataset - Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use subset function:

```
males <- subset(your_data, gender == "0")
females <- subset(your_data, gender == "1")
```

you can visit this [link](https://github.com/anasmorahhib/R-for-Data-Science/blob/master/ex1-Introduction-to-the-data-R/Introduction-to-the-data-R.Rmd) for more examples.